# Transform XML using XSLT 3.0 How to select an element for output based on sibling element value

Tags: xml, xslt-3.0

I have an XML input as shown below. I want to print output of each customer information for fields Cust_1, Gender & Price. I only want to print the price of chairs with Red color. I tried using choose-when and if but not getting the desired output. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<Sales_Data>
    <Furniture>
        <Customer_Reference>Cust_1</Customer_Reference>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Chairs>
            <Color_Ref>Black</Color_Ref>
            <Price>
                <Unit_Price>1000</Unit_Price>
            </Price>
        </Chairs>
        <Chairs>
            <Color_Ref>Red</Color_Ref>
            <Price>
                <Unit_Price>1100</Unit_Price>
            </Price>
        </Chairs>
    </Furniture>
    <Furniture>
        <Customer_Reference>Cust_2</Customer_Reference>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Chairs>
            <Color_Ref>Blue</Color_Ref>
            <Price>
                <Unit_Price>950</Unit_Price>
            </Price>
        </Chairs>
        <Chairs>
            <Color_Ref>Red</Color_Ref>
            <Price>
                <Unit_Price>1050</Unit_Price>
            </Price>
        </Chairs>
    </Furniture>
</Sales_Data>
```

Comment: You should show us your code so we can see where you went wrong. You have obviously misunderstood some aspect of the language spec, and if you showed us your mistakes then we could explain the concepts you are missing.

Comment: thanks, this has been resolved now

Answer (score 1):

To output the desired value, use the following XPath-1.0 expression

```
/Sales_Data/Furniture[Customer_Reference='Cust_1' and Gender='M']/Chairs[Color_Ref='Red']/Price/Unit_Price
```

or the full XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="/Sales_Data/Furniture[Customer_Reference='Cust_1' and Gender='M']/Chairs[Color_Ref='Red']/Price/Unit_Price"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both cases the output is the desired value `1100`.

Comment: Hi zx485,

Thanks for sharing your answer. There was a typo in my question, instead of stating customers I mentioned Cust_1. Regardless of that, I did follow the same XPATH as you've shared in your answer -> Chairs[Color_Ref='Red']. This worked fine for me.

Thanks again!